# How selecting uniques linestrings from two datasources with similar features?

Tags: qgis, select, linestring

I know is easy to select uniques points, or polygons features from two datasources (using centroids and overlap, or buffer) , but it not so easy do the same with linestrings, many times it is even a nightmare.

So,  how can you select uniques linestring from two datasources when there is very similar linestring features, some solaped, very near, o similar but not equals like this, or even more difficult, and if, in addition,  you also want to select the unique segments of those linestrings ?

[image: EXAMPLE two datasources with similar linestrings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share with you this technique that allows you to select those unique linestring elements from two different datasources.

What this technique do is:

- Split lines that crosses with another line (only do it over one datasource, the other datasource keep untouched)
- Create Black/White Mask from the untouched datasource.
- Select lines or portions of lines from second datasource whose length is at least within a percentage (user selection) in the appropriate area of the mask from first datasource.

The full technique, step by step with example images, is described here:
http://gisutilities.blogspot.com.es/2017/03/selecting-uniques-linestrings-features.html

This technique uses terminal commands line, QGIS, OpenJump and some script in python.

With this technique, you can get this (uniques linestring are green):

[image: Example, uniques lines, green, and original lines, red]

Comment: Please share more of your technique within your answer.